# Spring mvc annotation validation custom annotation

Tags: model-view-controller, spring, annotations

I have an @Password annotation that validates input for a valid password.
First I would like to check with @NotEmpty before even calling @Password to get better error messages.

If i use
@NotEmpty
@Password
String password;

I will get two different validation errors.

I have tried with groups but then all fields belonging to the group must pass validation before validating the Password.

Is there a good way to solve this problem? 
Currently I have included the @Not Empty in the @Password implementation but is this the best way to do it?

Comment: Please make clear what you want: a single error message, or different error messages?

Answer (score 0):

I guess `@Password` is a custom contraint that you have.  If you rather want to display a common or aggregated error message, irrespective of which validation failed, then you may want to use `@ReportAsSingleViolation`

```
...
@NotNull
@Size(min = 6)
@ReportAsSingleViolation
public @interface Password {
...
```

Irrespective of which validation failed, this will display the message associated with `@Password`.  Here a generic message can be specified.

Comment: No I actually would like to do the exact opposite. I have 3 different messages in @Passwrd + 1 in @NotEmpty and would like to get a more specific message. The problem is that I get 2 validation errors, one from @NotEmpty and one from @Password if I send in an empty String "".